# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute error

Tags: spring

I am new on spring. I am just trying to create my own CRUD OneToMany project. I have user and course table in my database. Course table has user_id foreign key references user(id).

When user successfully logged into the page, homePage.jsp comes and user courses are listed. When we click "Add Course" button in homePage.jsp, course-form.jsp file comes and we should add course.

The problem is, when I try to add course, I lost my user modelAttribute because in this time another attribute is on process with spring mvc.

When addedCourse form action performed these error occurs,

```
 Cannot invoke "com.veg.entity.User.addCourse(com.veg.entity.Course)" because "user" is null


org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
```

My Controller,

```
@PostMapping("/showFormForAdd")
    public String showFormForAdd(@ModelAttribute("user") User theUser, Model theModel) {
        
        Course theCourse = new Course();
        
        theCourse.setUser(theUser);
        
        theModel.addAttribute("course", theCourse);
        
        theModel.addAttribute("user", theUser);
        
        return "course-form";
    }   
    
    @PostMapping("addedCourse")
    public String addedCourse(@ModelAttribute("course") Course theCourse, Model theModel) {
        
        User user = theCourse.getUser();
        
        userService.save(user, theCourse);
        
        theModel.addAttribute("user", user);
        
        return "homePage";
    }
```

homePage.jsp

```
        
        
            <p>Welcome ${user.username}</p>
            
            <span>
            
                <form:form action="showFormForAdd" modelAttribute="user" method="POST">
                
                    <form:hidden path="username"/>
                    <form:hidden path="password"/>
                    
                    <input type="submit" value="Add Course" class="add-course"/>
                    
                </form:form>
                
            </span>
            
        
        
        
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Course id</th>
                        <th>Course title</th>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <c:forEach var="temp" items="${user.courses}">
                        
                        <tr>
                                
                            <td> ${temp.id} </td>
                            <td> ${temp.title} </td>
                                
                        </tr>           
                        
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

course-form.jsp

```
<p>Welcome ${user.username}</p>
            
    <span>
        <form:form action="loggedUser" modelAttribute="user" method="POST">
                
            <form:hidden path="username"/>
            <form:hidden path="password"/>
                
            <input type="submit" value="Back to Course List" class="add-course"/>
                    
        </form:form>
    </span>
            
            
        
        <!-- In the below I lost my user modelAttribute because I should use course attribute -->

    <form:form action="addedCourse" modelAttribute="course" method="POST">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td> Title </td>
                    <td> <form:input path="title"/> </td>
                </tr>
                            
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"> 
                    <input type="submit" value="Add Course" class="add-course"/> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
            
            </tbody>
        </table>
                    
    </form:form>
```

I have @Transactional in my service, @Repository in my DAO and there is no problem with sessionFactory.